# Grease Pencil Line Art - Limiting silhouette stroke extents

Tags: materials, grease-pencil, lineart

I'm using the Grease Pencil line art modifier to render outlines on very simple meshes. Just planar squares and circles for the moment.

By default, the Line Art modifier will draw a GP stroke around the entirety of an object's silhouette, e.g. the four edges of a mesh plane. Is it possible to, for example, not have one edge of a plane receive a GP stroke? My first thought was to tag the edge as a hard edge or crease and then switch that off, but there is no corresponding setting in the LA modifier to **not** render edges/creases.

The Line Art modifier will accept multiple entries in the material properties, and it is possible to create a standard stroke material for where I want outlines, as well as a holdout or fully transparent material for where I don't. But I don't understand how to assign these different materials to different edges of a single mesh, or if that is even possible. The Line Art modifier is applied to a LineArt object which is entirely separate from the mesh object I want to define the materials on, so it's not like I can set materials on selected edges in edit mode. Is this where pass index or material masks are used? The Blender documentation isn't very helpful in the practical applications of either.